# Ros_Controllers Package Catkin_Make Error

Tags: ros, catkin-make, ros-controllers

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There seems to be an error when looking to catkin_make the Ros_Controllers package:

```
-- ==> add_subdirectory(ros_controllers/joint_state_controller)
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'joint_trajectory_controller'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(ros_controllers/joint_trajectory_controller)
CMake Error at ros_controllers/joint_trajectory_controller/CMakeLists.txt:116 (add_rostest_gtest):
  Unknown CMake command "add_rostest_gtest".


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
Invoking "cmake" failed
```

Checking github shows some recent changes linked with add_rostest_gtest, though I'm not sure if this is the reason for catkin_make failing?

Anyone else able to install the package

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/76018/ros_controllers-package-catkin_make-error/) by [cdrwolfe](https://answers.ros.org/users/5809/cdrwolfe/) on ROS Answers with karma: 137 on 2013-09-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The controller should be searching for the rostest dependency correctly ([see here](https://github.com/ros-controls/ros_controllers/blob/hydro-devel/joint_trajectory_controller/CMakeLists.txt#L63)). Could it be that you have an older version of rostest installed?. The `add_rostest_gtest` function is relatively new. Could you check if your rostest installation contains [this](https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/blob/groovy-devel/tools/rostest/cmake/rostest-extras.cmake.em#L61) CMake function?.

---

Originally posted by [Adolfo Rodriguez T](https://answers.ros.org/users/410/adolfo-rodriguez-t/) with karma: 3907 on 2013-09-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [fritz](https://answers.ros.org/users/6370/fritz/) on 2013-09-04**:
Solved my problem.. Thx

**Comment by [Dave Coleman](https://answers.ros.org/users/1279/dave-coleman/) on 2013-09-05**:
This new function has not been released into Groovy yet, for some reason. So ros_controllers is failing to build, causing gazebo_ros_pkgs to fail building as well :/

The ros_comm repo is on version 1.9.48 but the corresponding Groovy debians is only on 1.9.47, which does not contain the `add_rostest_gtest` function.

**Comment by [Adolfo Rodriguez T](https://answers.ros.org/users/410/adolfo-rodriguez-t/) on 2013-09-05**:
The version of ros_controllers that uses `add_rostest_gtest` has been only released in Hydro. As Hydro diverges from Groovy these things will happen more and more (confessions of a Fuerte user ;-). I'd suggest that you overlay ros_comm with the Hydro equivalent, or if that doesn't work, with the Groovy version and add the extra CMake function manually.

**Comment by [Dave Coleman](https://answers.ros.org/users/1279/dave-coleman/) on 2013-09-05**:
I agree, but we have been telling lots of Gazebo users to install ros_control pkgs from source for Groovy and until now its been no problem. Ideally, the ros_controllers hydro branch should feature freeze and we begin development on a new indigo branch.

**Comment by [Adolfo Rodriguez T](https://answers.ros.org/users/410/adolfo-rodriguez-t/) on 2013-09-05**:
It should strive to not break the (C++, ROS) API within a ROS distro. It's possible to revert the change and use a more verbose cmake command combination, though.

**Comment by [Dave Coleman](https://answers.ros.org/users/1279/dave-coleman/) on 2013-09-05**:
I think if we just create a new release of ros_comm into Groovy the problem should be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Make sure to find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS rostest) which will include the CMake code containing the function "add_rostest_gtest".

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2013-09-02

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [cdrwolfe](https://answers.ros.org/users/5809/cdrwolfe/) on 2013-09-02**:
Sorry but could you extrapolate on that a bit :), do you mean add this line to a CMakeLists file, if so which one?